Cosmos ChangeFeed date range
I'm working with Azure Cosmos DB NoSQL API and need to reprocess changes from the Change Feed within a specified date range or between two continuation tokens using the Java SDK.
Based on the documentation, I didn't find a direct option to filter changes by a date range. My use case requires retrieving changes that occurred between specific timestamps or by providing two continuation tokens.
Is there any way to implement this functionality using the Java SDK, or is there an alternative approach to achieve this? Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.
I've implemented like below, But as per Azure docs lsn will be tagged to multiple updated items, I know we can use setStartTime what about endTime(If possible I need documents which got updated to future date) or Can i implement in a way comparing b/w two continuationToken.
@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    ChangeFeedProcessorOptions options = new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions();
    AtomicReference<ChangeFeedProcessor> changeFeedProcessorRef = new AtomicReference<>();

    ChangeFeedProcessor changeFeedProcessor = new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder()
            .hostName("Reprocess_LocalHost")
            .feedContainer(feedContainerId)
            .leaseContainer(leaseContainerId)
            .options(options)
            .handleChanges(changes -> {
                System.out.println("Start");
                for (JsonNode document : changes) {
                    long currentLsn = document.get("_lsn").asLong();
                    if (currentLsn <= toTokenLsn) {
                        System.out.println(" handleChanges() RECEIVED (within range): " + document.toPrettyString());
                    }
                    if (currentLsn >= toTokenLsn) {
                        System.out.println("Reached the specified toToken LSN: " + toTokenLsn + ". Stopping processing.");
                        ChangeFeedProcessor processorInstance = changeFeedProcessorRef.get();
                        if (processorInstance != null) {
                            processorInstance.stop()
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                                    .doOnSuccess(avoid -> System.out.println("Change Feed Processor has been stopped successfully."))
                                    .doOnError(error -> System.err.println("Failed to stop the Change Feed Processor: " + error))
                                    .subscribe();
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("End");
            })
            .buildChangeFeedProcessor();

    changeFeedProcessorRef.set(changeFeedProcessor);
    changeFeedProcessor.start().block();
    return true;
}


It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide a [mcve], and to show how you're setting up your changefeed processor. The Java SDK has setStartTime() which might be what you're missing, but... you've shown no code, as written.

Hey David, Thanks for replying me back, Could you please check my code once again, setStartTime() works but is there any way can i do date range (include an option like endTime)

There's no range option.

You can set a Start Date and then, process items and ignore those for which the _ts property shows that it's an item that is after your End Date.
There is no range filter available out of the box.

What if some of the documents got changed and moved to Future date?
And more clarification So can i run two different services one is for real time changes and other one is for reprocessing the changes from a specific timestamp

If a document gets modified, yes, the _ts gets updated, so it will be moved to a future batch of notifications.
If you run 2 services, then you could consider the 1st "done" once you cannot find any document where _ts is < EndTime after some predefined time.



I want to monitor 4 containers, can i use single lease container to create all lease documents for all to be monitored containers?


So i can run two different services one is for real time changes which we wont stop and other service to reprocess the changes from a specific time stamp and stop it ?



yes, the id of the change feed lease and position document is composed of the processor name plus the database + the container, so all the leases can safely coexist in a single container as you suggest

As long as both processors have different setLeasePrefix, yes. Make sure to watch for throttling though. Official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-processor?tabs=java#share-the-lease-container
